# modification of Orientation of bone Assimp

Tags: c++, animation, opengl, transformation, assimp

i have loaded a model with Assimp, i had to rotate the modelMatrix by 90 degrees on X axis do  see the model in screen .

when i am executing animation it works. But what i am tryning to do is to map the bone with a motion capture data. i have local rotation for each joint and when applying transformation to the bone it goes wrong.

Does the fact that the model is rotated by 90 degrees affect the rotation of bone or is it something else ? i keep the position and scale of the model from file by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply this to the Offsetmatrices for each bone as well. Normally we have the local transformation in bone-space for each bone and using the whole animation chain the global bone-transformation stored in the offset-matrix.

So you need to update the offset-matrices as well. More can be found here: [Assimp-Wiki abouf Offset-Matrices](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-offset-matrix)